# Excel 365 HYPERLINK and converting a column to active links

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, microsoft-excel-365

I have a column of web addresses, some as abc.com and others as https://def.com. How do I go about converting the entire column to active hyperlinks? The abc.com seems to require the https:// in front of it from the experimentation I've done. I am a neophyte so rather complete instructions necessary.

Although this worked, and the destination column filled with the proper hyperlink, and I dragged to the bottom of the destination column and everything changed as it should, I am left with still needing the original column in existence. If I clear the original column the destination only has "https://" and no actual destination. I know there is a way to copy the destination column and paste it so that the link doesn't refer to the original column, but everything I tried removes the hyperlink. How do I clear/delete the original column and leave the destination as a true hyperlink?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I used =HYPERLINK(A2) and copied down. It works for those "https://def.com" entries but not the abc.com. A popup says it can't open the file.

Comment: @Clayton, instead of responding to clarifications here in the comments [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1790226/edit) and add those details into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `IF` function to test if the cell already starts with *http* and if not then add it to the `HYPERLINK`.

Something like:

```
=IF(LEFT(A2,4)="http",HYPERLINK(A2),HYPERLINK("http://"&A2))
```

---

If you then want to have the hyperlinks as hyperlinks directly not as a formula, you can:

1. Copy the cells in `B` (or whatever column you put the above formula)
2. Paste ***Values*** to column `A` (where the original data was) and you can delete column `B`
3. To make column `A` hyperlinks now (that all have `http://`), select the range in column `A` that has these links, and run this VBA macro:

Open the VBA window using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>, selected all code in the window and paste this, then press the green Run arrow key on top of it:

```
Sub HyperAdd()
Dim xCell As Range
    For Each xCell In Selection
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=xCell, Address:=xCell.Formula
    Next xCell
End Sub
```

---

And to be honest if we need VBA let's do the whole thing in VBA...

Select the range in column `A` (do not select the whole column, select only the range you have values in), and open VBA and paste and run this code:

```
Sub AddHTTPandHyperlink()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    
    ' Check if any cells are selected
    If Selection.Cells.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No cells selected."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Loop through each selected cell
    For Each rng In Selection
        ' Check if the cell value is a string and doesn't start with "http://"
        If TypeName(rng.Value) = "String" And Not rng.Value Like "http://*" Then
            rng.Value = "http://" & rng.Value ' Add "http://" to the beginning
        End If
    Next rng

    'Converts each text hyperlink selected into a working hyperlink
    For Each xCell In Selection
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=xCell, Address:=xCell.Formula
    Next xCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Although this worked, and the destination column filled with the proper hyperlink, and I dragged to the bottom of the destination column and everything changed as it should, I am left with still needing the original column in existence. If I clear the original column the destination only has "https://" and no actual destination. I know there is a way to copy the destination column and paste it so that the link doesn't refer to the original column, but everything I tried removes the hyperlink. How do I clear/delete the original column and leave the destination as a true hyperlink?

Comment: For that I believe you'd need a VBA macro, is that acceptable for you?

Comment: Yes, with guidance on how to make VBA macro to work.

Comment: @Clayton, added VBA code.

Comment: I get a compile error: Invalid procedure. I am not VBA/excel literate. Sorry. I have my column and opened the vba window and pasted the code and hit the green arrow. I know I am doing something simple and wrong. Any help?

Comment: You selected the whole column or only the range that has data in them?

Comment: only the range. I thank you but I have decided to do it by hand. I even asked chatai and chatgpt and they couldn't get it right. They just wrote HYPERLINK at the beginning of each item:<))